# In RLC circuit, if source voltage $V(t)=V_p \sin(\omega t)$ then $V_p= \sqrt{V_{R,p}^2+(V_{L,p}-V_{C,p})^2}$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, inductance

Consider an [RLC circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RLC_circuit),
$\hspace{200px}$[image],
and let $V_p$ be the amplitude of voltage from alternating current source,$$
V\left(t\right)~=~V_p \sin{\left(\omega t\right)}
\,.$$In addition, let $V_{p,\,\text{resistor}}, V_{p,\,\text{coil}}, V_{p,\,\text{capacitor}}$ be amplitudes of voltage across the resistor, coil, and capacitor, respectively.

Then does$$
V_p = \sqrt{V_{p,\,\text{resistor}}^2+ {\left(V_{p,\,\text{coil}}-V_{p,\,\text{capacitor}} \right)}^2}
$$
hold?

Comment: Is the $p$ ("_peak_"?) subscript information worth retaining in this context, or could it be dropped for brevity?

Comment: Nat, the "p" is to make it absolutely clear that the voltages are Peak and not RMS, which is most common in electrical engineering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the RLC circuit has R, L, and C **connected in series** and V(t) is the voltage across the complete series, the answer is yes:

$$V_p=\sqrt{V_{R_p}^2+(V_{L_p}-V_{C_p})^2}$$

Comment: You accidentally squared the left hand side :)